# kendo ui jquery printing tabs

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I have read the Kendo UI JQuery documentation and other forum responses to the question of how to print the Kendo UI Jquery tabstrip. But I am having an issue still. If I open a window and do nothing (e.g click on no tabs/etc) and use the browser to print I can print all the tabs just fine like the solutions mentioned. The problem is when I click on a tab and then another and maybe go back to another (whatever the combination would be) I am only seeing the tab I just clicked or in sometimes I am only seeing the tab I just clicked but the last one, for example. I no longer see all the tabs in print preview after I start using the window. Any suggestions?

```
@media print
{
    body > *
    {
        display: none !important;
    }

    body > .k-window
    {
        display: block !important;
        position: relative !important;
        top: auto !important;
        left: auto !important;
        width: auto !important;
        height: auto !important;
        border-width: 0;
        box-shadow: none !important;
    }

    .k-window .k-window-titlebar
    {
        display: none;
    }

    .k-tabstrip .k-content
    {
        display: block;
    }    



}
```

I have played around with the above CSS but with no luck. The only change I can affect is that I can get it to where adding in the kendo ui's k-item element the user can print each tab one at a time if they are on that tab and decide to use the browser to print. other than that I cannot get all the tabs to print all the time.